# Using Mindsqualls and C# to program LEGO Mindstorms

Tags: c#, dll, lego-mindstorms

I am working on a program to run a LEGO NXT from a computer. I found the [MindSqualls](http://www.mindsqualls.net/Default.aspx) .NET library for working with the LEGO NXT, but I have no idea what to do with the DLL and/or the c# libraries to get the software working.

I first downloaded the DLL version, trying them in all of the different folders in the project. Yet when I try to use the with the code:

```
using NKH.MindSqualls;
```

I get the error

> The type or namespace name 'NKH' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I get the same error when I tried downloading the c# projects and including them in my solution.

Does anyone know how I would include the DLLs or the c# projects in such a way that I could use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to right-click the project, click Add Reference, then select the DLL file.

Comment: @jk144 If this solved your problem don't forget to accept this answer (click the tick mark under the vote count for this answer)

Comment: Done (StackOverflow requires a wait of 15 minutes, had to wait until that was up)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause of this error is when there is a version mismatch between the referenced DLL and the target .Net version of your project.

This can occur if you try to use a version of the DLL built for a newer .Net version than the target .Net version of your project e.g. trying to use a .Net 4.0 DLL on a .Net 2.0 project